# Proper way to do calculations using PHP?

Tags: php

I need to calculate `ex_vat` then echo the result also I need to calculate `inc_vat` echo the result.

It also needs to be rounded to 2 decimal places.

Basically it doesn't work, the calculation does nothing it just displays:

£29.17 inc VAT
£29.1700 ex VAT

I don't know the proper syntax for this, which is why I'm asking on here, thanks!

Code:

```
$req4 = $con->query("SELECT price, vat_rate FROM product WHERE product_id='$prodId'");
$row4 = $req4->fetch_row();

$price_ex_vat = $row4[0];
$vat_rate = $row4[1];
$price_inc_vat = 0;
$price_inc_vat = $price_ex_vat + ($price_inc_vat * $vat_rate / 100);
```

Comment: The [PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/) is a good resource for learning how to do things in PHP. StackOverflow is more for helping through problems that occur when trying to implement something.

Comment: Does this work currently? If so, what is your goal? To just clean it up, or add the decimal points, and round to the nearest hundredth?

Comment: Your calculation are correct as you want maybe?, though you just have forgotten to insert a value to $price_inc_vat which you have used is this line ($price_inc_vat * $vat_rate / 100); this will give you an error because $price_inc_vat is not existing as a variable. Try setting a value on that first.

Comment: How is your vat_rates stored? Is it 20 or 0.2?

Comment: Try to set $price_inc_vat = 29.17; got this value in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line

```
$price_inc_vat = $price_ex_vat + ($price_inc_vat * $vat_rate / 100);
```

you are calling a variable "$price_inc_vat" which is not existing yet.
you may want to assign a value to that variable before using it.

like

```
$price_inc_vat = 29.17;
$price_inc_vat = $price_ex_vat + ($price_inc_vat * $vat_rate / 100);
```

now to round this to 2 decimal places just do the ff:

```
$price_inc_vat = 29.17;
$price_inc_vat = $price_ex_vat + ($price_inc_vat * $vat_rate / 100);
$price_inc_vat = round($price_inc_vat, 2);
```

Comment: As i mentioned its only a example. He can change it to the value he wants! Dude pull your self up.

Comment: Well if thats what you and the questioner believe to be LOGIC then heaven help us!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `price_ex_vat` in the calculation i.e. the price you read from the database row, and not the value you are trying to calculate $price_inc_vat.

```
$req4 = $con->query("SELECT price, vat_rate FROM product WHERE product_id='$prodId'");
$row4 = $req4->fetch_row();

$price_ex_vat = $row4[0];
$vat_rate = $row4[1];

// if $vat_rate is 0.2
$price_inc_vat = round( $price_ex_vat + ($price_ex_vat * $vat_rate), 2 );

// if $vat_rate = 20
$price_inc_vat = round( $price_ex_vat + ($price_ex_vat * ($vat_rate/100)), 2 );
```